# python - MariaDB "unknown column in field" issue

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mariadb

So I've succeeded in saving the python query result into csv files so far. It was all good.

But I'm now struggling with saving the result into MariaDB.

[The dataframe that keeps showing error messages whenever I try to save it into MariaDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7nzD.png)

What I can't really understand is that there is no problem saving the same data when setting the time as '2017-02-01 to 2020-04-20', but the error message `sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'")` pops up when I switch the starting timeline any date before 2017-02-01 (e.g. timeframe as '2015-06-15 to 2020-04-20') even though I have the data starting from 2015-08-21.

[The dataframe well saved into MariaDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4aTU.png)

As you can see the dataframe starting from 2007-02-01 which has been transmitted to MariaDB without any problem, I have no column named 'inf' either in the python dataframe or the SQL table.

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO equitiesdailyprice (`Quote`, `Date`, `Close`, `PriceDiff`, `Volume`, `VolDiff`, `Open`, `High`, `Low`) 
VALUES (%(Quote)s, %(Date)s, %(Close)s, %(PriceDiff)s, %(Volume)s, %(VolDiff)s, %(Open)s, %(High)s, %(Low)s)]
```

Comment: Find a way, with the MySQL library you are using, to view the generated SQL.  Intuition suggests that `inf` might be "infinity" (e.g. `VALUES(..., inf, ...)`which would be an extremely incorrect thing to appear in the generated SQL, but since you do have some `NaN` appearing in your last image, `inf` doesn't seem like such a long shot.  An unquoted string in the values section of the query would be interpreted by MariaDB as a column name, thus *unknown column 'inf' in 'field list'*.

Comment: That form of data substitution is begging for "Sql injection".  Use binding or at least escaping and quoting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `inf` is internally floating point infinity, and your python connector (possibly `pymysql`?) is converting this to `inf`, and MariaDB doesn't know how to represent infinity in a column.